# Using the following code The Nested else if statement, not printing please help what is the reason this code is not executed

Tags: java

**Using the following code I am looking the highest number of the variable,The Nested else if statement, not printing please help what is the reason this code is not executed**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Nestedifelese {
        static int A;
        static int B;
        static int C;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner obj= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the A object number :");
        A=obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the B object number :");
        B=obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the C object number :");
        C=obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The value of A is"+ A);
        System.out.println("The value of B is"+ B);
        System.out.println("The value of C is"+ C);
        
        if(A>=B) 
        {
            if (A>=C) 
            {
                System.out.println("The Higgest number is" +A);
            }
        }       
        else if (B>=A) 
        {
            if (B>=C) 
            
            {
                System.out.println("The Higgest number is" +B);
            }
        }
        else if (C>=A) 
        {
            if (C>=B) 
            
            {
                System.out.println("The Higgest number is" +C);
            }           
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

At least one of `A>=B` and `B>=A`will be true so it never reaches `else if (C>=A)`. If you want to use if-else instead of the `Math.max` function, change the `else if` to `if` should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Skylar your suggestion it's work, now the code is executed

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in if conditions. Your second condition `B>=A` is exact opposite of first condition `A>=B`. So if first condition will be false then second condition will always be true and it will never reach to third condition.

You should use `Math.max` to filter our highest number of else you can change your if conditions like this:

```
        if(A>=B && A>=C) {
            System.out.println("The Higgest number is" +A);
        } 
        if (B>=A && B>=C) {
            System.out.println("The Higgest number is" +B);
        }
        if (C>=A && C>=B) {
            System.out.println("The Higgest number is" +C);         
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove static before int, I don't see any use of it.
Follow Variables standard, instead of UPPER A,B,C use lowercase;

And here is the answer:

```
    int highestNumber = Math.max(Math.max(a,b),c);
    System.out.println("The Highest number is" +highestNumber);
```